# Microsoft Edge DevTools is closing automatically

Tags: browser, crash, devtools

After opening developer tools in Microsoft Edge Version 116.0.1938.69 (Official Build for Windows) (64-bit), it closes after 5 seconds.

I've already tried restoring the default settings, but the problem persists. Edge is managed by my company.

On my personal laptop this does not happen with the same version. Anyone else having this problem and know how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: It worked here now. I simply deleted the subfolders within the following folder C:\Users\{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked here now (on windows). I simply deleted the subfolders within the following folder

C:\Users\{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge

The folder will be automatically recreated after the browser is opened again.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed similar issue happening on my Edge browser using Windows 11, Edge browser Version 116.0.1938.69 (Official build) (64-bit). After everything from reinstalling, repairing, and this is what worked for me:

- Sign out of your profile (make sure to check the "Clear favorites,
  history, passwords, and other browsing data from this device." box.
- Close all Edge instances (you might have use Task Manager for any
  remaining Edge instances)
- Open Edge, sign back into your profile let it sync your data.

These steps took care of my issue with DevTools closing automatically after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into this issue as well (`Version 116.0.1938.81 (Official build) (arm64)`).

The issue, at least for me, happened after I added a root folder to DevTools.
[image: set root folder]

To fix it, you can edit the Preferences file to remove the set folder.

- First, completely quit Edge.
- On a Mac, navigate to `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge/Profile 1` and open the `Preferences` file.
- The data should be in JSON format. Find the `file_system_paths` key under `devtools` and delete it with whatever value was set.
- Save the file, and start Edge again. When you open DevTools, it should no longer disappear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (using `Version 116.0.1938.69 (Official build) (arm64)` on MacBook Air with Ventura 13.5.1).

I moved the following directories into the Trash and restarted the Edge, then I did not replicate this issue:

- `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge`
- `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge Beta`
- `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge Canary`
- `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge Dev`

You may need to reconfigure your Edge since all preferences are cleared.

I know it's not the ideal solution, and I am still unsure what the root cause of this issue is.